# Executing Block of Transactions on Iceberg Table using Spark SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I want to execute a DELETE and then an INSERT on an iceberg table. However I want to execute them as a block so either both succeed or none. My iceberg table is in glue data catalog. I tried executing the two statements as a block however it throws a parse exception. If I run the queries separetly, then it executes without any issues. Any ideas?

Here's my code snippet-

```
update_query =  """
                DELETE FROM glue_catalog.{}.{};
                INSERT INTO glue_catalog.{}.{} SELECT * FROM incoming_data;
                """ .format(self.dest_schema,self.dest_table,self.dest_schema,self.dest_table)
print(update_query)
self.spark.sql(update_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jatin for raising this question. What you're looking for is the `INSERT OVERWRITE` operation:

```py
update_query = f"""
    INSERT OVERWRITE glue_catalog.{self.dest_schema}.{self.dest_table} SELECT * FROM incoming_data;
"""
print(update_query)
self.spark.sql(update_query)
```

This will either fail or complete with deletion as an atomic operation.

Comment: Thanks Fokko! 
1. Iceberg documentation suggests using spark dynamic partition overwrite mode when using INSERT OVERWRITE. But this mode only overwrites the partitions for which there's data in the incoming feed. I want to do replace the entire contents. Hence I went DELETE -> INSERT route.
 2. I also want to do an upsert in my code for icremental runs where I want to insert new records and update existing. I cannot use MERGE INTO because I have multiple records in my source feed matching the target which Iceberg doesn't allow. [link] (https://rb.gy/dkr4pp) Hence I am using DELETE -> INSERT.